# how to set up a contract between a server and client in C#

Tags: c#, client

I have been searching for hours and hours and I cannot find a good tutorial on how to make a Client Application and a Server Application that I can use RMI in c#. I want to set something up where multiple clients can connect to the server (I know I can do something asynchronously, but I don't know how) but how does RMI work? and how would I implement it?

I have seen several samples of code that have a client that uses a dll ( or a copy of a contract) and a server that uses a dll (or a copy of the contract) and the client sends parameters to the server and the server calculates it then sends the result back to the client, for the user. but none of the examples I have been able to find work, they all end up having errors that I cannot figure out because I don't know the subject well enough.

If you have any good links with code that works so I can learn by tinkering that would be great, or if you know of a different implementation approach that would be easier that would be great too.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I guess, instead of searching for hours, if you just searched for this `using RMI in C#` on Google, you would get the answer.

Here is a link for what I found: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwdt6w2k%28VS.85%29.aspx, .NET Framework Remoting. Ok, next! The other thing that I found on some other posts was this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx WCF (Windows Communication Foundation)

I would like to ask you, if you ever want to find help for C#, just try to search in http://msdn.microsoft.com they would help you out!

You said, you donot know the subject well. Well first try to learn what subject is about. First learn the basics about what you are going to do, and how to handle the code you are using. For C# I would go for http://www.codeproject.com or http://msdn.microsoft.com they both provide a very well explained tutorial for C#. However there are other example on http://stackoverflow.com too. You can search for tags buddy. Gud luck! :)